# Removing constexpr changes values of array on gcc

Tags: c++, c++14, constexpr, compiler-bug

When trying to answer to a question and create a `constexpr std::array`, I wrote

```
// Own implementation as std::array::operator[] is not constexpr :/
template <typename T, std::size_t N>
struct array
{
    constexpr T& operator[] (std::size_t index) { return data[index];}
    constexpr const T& operator[] (std::size_t index) const { return data[index];}

    constexpr std::size_t size() const { return N; }

    T data[N];
};

constexpr array<std::size_t, 1001u> make_bottle_count()
{
    array<std::size_t, 1001u> a = {{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1}};
    for (int i = 11; i != a.size(); ++i) {
        a[i] = 1 + std::min({a[i - 1], a[i - 5], a[i - 7], a[i - 10]});
    }
    return a;
}

int main() {
    // Change constexpr to const make gcc returns expected result
    constexpr auto bottle_count = make_bottle_count(); 

    std::cout << bottle_count[17] << std::endl;   // expect 2
    std::cout << bottle_count[65] << std::endl;   // expect 7
    std::cout << bottle_count[1000] << std::endl; // expect 100
}
```

but gcc gives unexpected results (`2` `2` `2`) whereas clang gives expected result.

[Live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2c9cf86d1f32cca3)

Removing `constexpr` (or replacing by `const`) for `bottle_count` gives expected results for both.

Do I invoke UB, or it is a compiler(gcc) bug ?

Comment: Same behaviour in gcc 6.0: http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/VpRHRxLGYj02Az04

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is a gcc bug, see: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=67104

I will add your testcase to the bug.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is the same bug. To me, it looks more like this issue is related to `initializer_list`: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0e0258b3a1a034dc But I admit, it might just be a weird effect of the bug you've linked.